# How to test ES6 modules (these with import) with mocha?

Tags: javascript, import, mocha.js

It is my first time with testing JS frontend and I chose mocha for that.
I have a class let us say `Market` which uses other classes I made.
I use `import ... from ...` clause and `export default Market` in the end.

so `Market` class looks like that:

```
import { math, AnotherClass, MyOtherClass } from '../index.js'
class Market {
  constructor () {
    // code here
  }
  methodToTest(input) {
    // some code here ...
    return output
  }
}
export default Market
```

and then my test.js

```
var assert = require('assert')
// import { Market } from '../public/mm/ai/Market.js'
var Market = require('../public/mm/ai/Market')

describe('Market', function() {
    describe('#methodToTest()', function() {
        it('should return 0 input is greater than mean + 4 * sigma', function() {
           var market = new Market()
           assert.equal(market.methodToTest(45), 0)
        })
    })
})
```

and after running the test I get the error:

```
import { math, AnotherClass, MyOtherClass } from '../index.js'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and an error stack.

And the question is: **How to make mocha test my modules with these imports?**
As you see I also tried to use import directly in test.js and it failed also.
But I don't want to rewrite my whole project to use `require` as it works perfectly fine in the browser as it is now.

Comment: Your tests also need to run through Babel.

Comment: But I was trying to test the class as it is before translating through Babel.

Comment: OK, so I guess I don't get this whole mess of JS tools.

Comment: Welcome to the club. It also depends if you're running the tests in the browser or from the command line--but bottom line is that the tests also need to be babelized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the solution myself.

1. **Babel & mocha** - the best, cause no intermediate files

First the **.mocharc.js** file to configure mocha to use babel and chai:

```
module.exports = {
    require: ['chai', '@babel/register'],
    ui: 'bdd',
    // ui: 'tdd',
    reporter: 'spec',
    growl: false,
};
```

I have chosen *ui:'bdd'* because I used the *describe* in test.js:
`describe('Market class:', function() {`

Secondly I added **babel** configuration in **package.json**:

```
"babel": {
    "env": {
      "test-console": {
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
      }
    ,
      "test": {
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "transform-remove-console"]
      }
    }
  },
```

Two environments to use with console output and wituhout it.
It leads to *package.json* scripts section to execute one of them:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "BABEL_ENV=test mocha || TRUE",
    "test-console-log": "BABEL_ENV=test-console mocha || TRUE"
  },
```

and now I was ready to have my **test.js** executed and imports in my modules worked.
Here is the head of **test.js**:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert
import Market from '../public/mm/ai/Market.js'
...
```

I switched to import when regarding my own modules.

2. **Webpack, babel & mocha**

Everything in webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: './test/test.js',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test/'),
      filename: 'exec_test.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
              compress: 
              {
                  drop_console: true
                }
            }
        })]
    }
};
```

and then you can build and run it by:

```
"scripts": {
   "build-tests-webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.test.js",
   "exec test": "mocha --ui bdd test/exec_test.js"
}
```

in **package.json**

Answer (score 6):

> For anyone who suffer from configuration

### 1. installation

You need to install mocha and @babel/XXX plugins

```
npm install mocha --save-dev
```

```
npm install @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/register --save-dev
```

Check the `package.json`. It might be like this

```json
{
  "scripts": { ... }
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.15.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.15.3",
    ...
    "mocha": "^9.1.2",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

- Version can be different

### 2. babel configuration

create babel configuration file `.babelrc` under the `[PROJECT-ROOT]`

```
[PROJECT-ROOT]
 +- src
 +- test
 +- package.json
 +- .babelrc (+)
```

And fill the content like this

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

### 3. test script runner

open `package.json` and find "scripts" block

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "build": ...,
     "start": ...,
  },
}
```

create "test" property with value `mocha --require @babel/register`

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "build": ...,
     "start": ...,
     "test": "mocha --require @babel/register"
  },
}
```

### 4. Samples

create a file(`calc.js`) to be tested, and test file(`calc.spec.js`)

```
[PROJECT-ROOT]
 +- src
     +- calc.js      (+)
 +- test
     +- calc.spec.js (+)
 +- package.json
 +- .babelrc
```

```js
// calc.js
const add = (a, b) => a + b
const mul = (a, b) => a * b

export default {
  add,
  mul
}
```

and test file `calc.spec.js`

```
// calc.spec.js
const assert = require('assert')
import calc from '../src/calc'

describe('testing calc.add, cal.mul', () => {
  it('should be seven', () => {
    const seven = calc.add(3, 4)
    assert.equal(7, seven)
  })
})
```

### 5. running test

input the `npm run test` in console

```sh
$ npm run test

  testing calc.add, cal.mul
    ✔ should be seven


  1 passing (7ms)
```

### 6. Reference

- https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/tree/master/packages/babel